# Mac OS X X11 gnome clients theme

Tags: macos, mac, gnome, themes, xorg

Is there any program to set the theme of x11 gnome applications under Mac OS X?

I've installed macports and gnome, but I cant find the gnome-theme-manager that I'm using when under linux.